# How to update column value of one dataframe with other dataframe value in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have following 2 dataframes -

df1:

```
                            job                                              e_msg
0  f_maf_crm_customer_request_global_jgvcc  permission denied for relation f_maf_custome
```

df2:

```
                 master_job                           error_msg      current_count
0    JGCC_Genesys_Conversations_Aggregates
1  f_maf_crm_customer_request_global_jgvcc                              100
```

if df1 is having the same job name so df2 should update error_msg with df1.e_msg and current_count should change as 0.

In final output:

```
             master_job                               error_msg                            current_count
0    JGCC_Genesys_Conversations_Aggregates
1  f_maf_crm_customer_request_global_jgvcc  permission denied for relation f_maf_custome     0
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, I ask that before asking a question, try to solve your problem and if there is a doubt, present the code and how far you have come, on this platform we do not do your job, we only help and take questions!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple approach would be this one liner.

```
df2.loc[df2.master_job.isin(df1.job), ['error_msg', 'current_count']] = [df1['e_msg'].values, 0]
```

This gives the output you want. Please note that I have abbreviated the `error_msg` for brevity. You can test it out yourself and see that the output message is the same as the one you are using.

```
    job                                     error_msg             current_count
0   JGCC_Genesys_Conversations_Aggregates       
1   f_maf_crm_customer_request_global_jgvcc permission denied...    0.0
```

What that single line of code does is quite simple. It checks if the records in `df1` exist in `df2` and if it does, then the values in `df2` are changed accordingly to match your requirement. You can read more about `isin` [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can try an outer join on the two dataframes from the `merge` function in `pandas`. If you don't know what joins are then refer to [this webpage](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/different-types-of-joins-in-pandas/).

Code -

```
merged_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on = "master_job", how = "outer")
merged_df
```

Output -

|  | master_job | error_msg_x | current_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | JGCC_Genesys_Conversations_Aggregates | nan |  |
| 1 | f_maf_crm_customer_request_global_jgvcc | permission denied for relation f_maf_custome | 100 |

---

Here we are getting two `error_msg` columns because `error_msg_x` is from `df1` and `error_msg_y` is from `df2`. Because `error_msg_y` isn't of any use to use, we can drop it using the code below.

```
merged_df = merged_df.drop(columns = "error_msg_y")
```

We can merge the two dataframes and drop the `error_msg_y` column in just one line using this code,

```
merged_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on = "master_job", how = "right").drop(columns = "error_msg_y")
```